# showing a lot of widgets in qt5 is slow

Tags: c++, qt5, qwidget

I'm developing an program that allows you to communicate with an Engine control unit of a small turbine. The ECU is configured using 255 8-bit numbers stored in an EEPROM (ECU communicates over RS232). each number represents one of the engine's settings.
So to make sense of this we have a file that describes the meaning of all these settings and this is loaded into my program, which generates a row of 15 standard QWidgets per setting.
I also implemented a way to categorize these settings, for example, all fuel consumption related settings belong to one category. there's a Qcombobox in which you can select which category you want to filter. clicking it calls the following function:

```
void MainWindow::on_listCategories_currentTextChanged(const QString &currentcategory) { //filter categories
//ui->checkBoxShowDifferences->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked); //ugly hack!!
setUpdatesEnabled(false);
if(currentcategory == "ALL") {
    for(int i=0; i<RegistrySettings.size(); i++) {
        if(RegistrySettings[i].Policy < static_cast<int>(TMC_Program.CurrentActiveAccessPolicy)) {
            hideOptionWidgets(RegistrySettings[i].address);
            continue;
        }
        if(ui->checkBoxShowDifferences->isChecked()) {
            if(RegistrySettings[i].value == RegistrySettings[i].compareValue) {
                hideOptionWidgets(RegistrySettings[i].address);
                continue;
            }
        }
        showOptionWidgets(RegistrySettings[i].address);
    }
} else {
    for(int i=0; i<RegistrySettings.size(); i++) {
        if(RegistrySettings[i].Policy < static_cast<int>(TMC_Program.CurrentActiveAccessPolicy)) {
            hideOptionWidgets(RegistrySettings[i].address);
            continue;
        }
        if(RegistrySettings[i].category != currentcategory) {
            hideOptionWidgets(RegistrySettings[i].address);
            continue;
        }
        if(ui->checkBoxShowDifferences->isChecked()) {
            if(RegistrySettings[i].value == RegistrySettings[i].compareValue) {
                hideOptionWidgets(RegistrySettings[i].address);
                continue;
            }
            showOptionWidgets(RegistrySettings[i].address);
        } else {
            hideOptionWidgets(RegistrySettings[i].address);
        }
    }
}
setUpdatesEnabled(true);
```

while hiding works perfectly fine, when selecting "ALL" it needs to show all the hidden widgets, this is incredibly slow! it takes around 5 seconds to display all the widgets!
The code responsible for showing all the widgets is this:

```
void MainWindow::showOptionWidgets(int addr) {
if(addr < 0 || addr > 255) {return;}
QStringList WidgetNames = generateOptionRowWidgetNames(addr);
for(int i=1; i<WidgetNames.size(); i++) { //number 0 is a qhboxlayout and not a qwidget so it won't find it
    QWidget* widgetToShow = ui->scrollAreaOptions->findChild<QWidget*>(WidgetNames[i]);
    if(widgetToShow && widgetToShow->isHidden()) {
        widgetToShow->show(); //extremely slow!
    }
}
```

}

is there a way to optimize this?

note: all widgets are standard ones! just labels, checkboxes and buttons, generate optionRowWidgetNames only generates a simple QStringlist with fixed strings that only have the corrosponding settings number attached to them.

Comment: Have you profiled this? That said, you're doing a lot of repetitive calls to `findChild()` based on a string. Why not store the widget pointers in a hash table?

Comment: I did try a hash table but that gives me segfaults since Qt is juggling with addresses under the hood. also hiding the widgets works as fast as it should be using this method, it's just the revealing.